# Angular templates grunt not loading

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

I have AngularJS project with more than 20 html templates (routes, modals).

I'm using [grunt-angular-templates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-angular-templates) to split tempaltes in one file templates.js.

In my Angular project I'm using angular-route 1.2.25 for routing.

When I try to use template from templates.js file, browser crashes and not responding. There is any error on console.

The problem is only with html templates with Angular stuff (ng-switch, ng-show etc.)
When I load clean html it works.

**I thing the problem is with compile the templates from $templateCache, but how o manage it?**

**Templates.js**

```
...
     $templateCache.put("name","HTML");
...
```

Comment: Can you share more information about your project structure and the grunt configuration for `angular-templates` task

Answer (score 0):

After long hours of search I found what's wrong.

In my solution I'm using Modal Boostrap for Angular. 
grunt-angular-templates plugin don't compile this templates correctly. I just skip this files and all works.